# When to use Microsoft Extensions Logging and Application Insights Asp NETCore in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, ilogger

I am so confused while enabling logging in azure functions in .NET Core 6 using application insights. I had explored lot of sites but still in dilemma what exactly the difference between the nuget packages and when to use at which situations.

`microsoft.extensions.logging.applicationinsights`

`microsoft.applicationinsights.aspnetcore`

I had understand that if we want custom telemetry, we should use `microsoft.applicationinsights.aspnetcore`

I had created separate azure functions with separate nuget packages and I am able to see logs.

With `microsoft.extensions.logging.applicationinsights` package and used `ILogger` in function classes.

I added below piece of code in  azure function startup

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new TelemetryConfiguration { ConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING")});
```

with `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` package , I injected Di and used `ITelemetryClient` in function classes

I added below piece of code in  azure function startup

```
var options = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions { ConnectionString = SharedMethods.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING") };
            builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options);
```